# Java interfaces in jar archives

Tags: java, servlets, interface

I'm studying `servlets` and I was looking at a fully working example created by my professor. The `service()` method of my servlet looks like this:

```
public void service (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) 
                        throws ServletException, IOException  {
    res.setContentType( "text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    out.println( "Some response" );
    out.close();
}
```

In the above example `service()` uses a `ServletResponse` object, so I went into my `servlet-api .jar`, searched for `javax.servlet.ServletResponse.class` and found out that `ServletResponse.class` is an interface (`public abstract interface javax.servlet.ServletResponse`) . So in my code I use an object of type `ServletResponse` which is an interface, but I thought that you could not instantiate an interface in Java. I also noticed that this interface is implemented by `ServletResponseWrapper.class`.

So my questions are:

- Why does compiler let me instantiate an interface?
- why don't we use a ServletResponseWrapper object?

Comment: Do you instatiate it? show us the init code, please.

Comment: Using anonymous class you could instantiate it. Otherwise it's possible to instantiate a class which implements that interface and then cast to it (polymorphism) the best example is with `List` -> `List myList = new ArrayList();`

Comment: The servlet container will pass an object of a container specific class that implements the interface `ServletResponse`. All you need to know about it is that it implements the interface.

Comment: ok so let's say I'm using Apache Tomcat as servlet container, it's Tomcat who passes an object that implements ServletResponse interface when calling service method. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't instantiating the interface `ServletResponse`. You are using a reference that was passed to you by the servlet container when it calls the `service()` method on your servlet. The container instantiates a class that implements `ServletRepsonse` interface. The  instantiated (concrete) class could be `ServletResponseWrapper` or any other "internal" classes as long as it implements the `ServletResponse` interface.

Try printing `res.getClass().getName()` in your `service()` method. It should tell you the exact class name that's being instantiated by the servlet container.

Comment: Thanks Bloody. you are right, I did not instantiate anything after all.

Comment: With your advice, I found out that the class who implements the interface is `@org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade`. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you did instantiate a `ServletResponse`; you're simply using an instance that was passed to you. You don't care about the implementation details; you just care about the contract specified by the interface.

An interface specified the contact and there could be a variety of implementations for it. They could each implement the contract in different ways but they behavior of each would be exactly the same (matching what is specified in the interface).